# How to write the test script for tapping a screen point in flutter integration testing without using flutter_test.dart package?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-test

I use flutter_driver for integration testing in my application. I need to tap a screen point by passing an offset value in flutter driver testing, without using a flutter_test package

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this using adb (Android Debug Bridge, a command-line tool for Android).
This way you can perform actions, like a tap gesture, directly on the emulator. You need to make sure the adb path is correct though.

Let me give you a small example:

```
String adbPath() {
  return join(envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT'] ?? envVars['ANDROID_HOME'], 'platform-tools', Platform.isWindows ? 'adb.exe' : 'adb');
}


void tap(int x, int y) {
  Process.run(_adbPath(), ['shell', 'input', 'tap', x.toString(), y.toString()]);
}
```

No need to import the flutter_test package.